# ¿Cómo añadir el otro 50% del background de color gris?

Tags: html5, css3

Cuando el asistente está en el primer paso, se muestra el 50% de la barra de color verde, pero el color gris desaparece dejando un 50% faltante.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el segundo paso la barra pasa a continuar al 100%, y el mismo problema anterior.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Nota:** Para ir viendo como funciona los pasos deben cambiar y añadir nuevo elementos es decir si desean observar el proceso del segundo paso, añadir la clase `active` al segundo `li` y en `data-active=""` añadir el número `2`

**Entonces cómo puedo añadir el resto faltante de color gris.**

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 73px;
}

.progressbar {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.progressbar li > * {
  border: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18823529411764706);
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: rgba(44, 63, 76, 0.6196078431372549);
  top: -70px;
  background-color: rgba(237, 239, 240, 0.61);
}

.progressbar li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  display: block;
  text-align:  center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #edeff0;
}
  
.progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #edeff0;
  top: 4px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
  
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
  
.progressbar li.active span {
  color: green;
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.1);
}

.progressbar li.active:before {
 background-color: green;
 -webkit-transition: background 300ms ease;
 transition: background 300ms ease;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 300ms;
 transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.progressbar li.active + li:after {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
}

.progressbar:after {
  content: "";
  height: 4px;
  left: 16.666%;
  background: green;
  top: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: width 300ms ease;
  transition: width 300ms ease;
}

.progressbar[data-active="1"]:after {
  width: 0;
}

.progressbar[data-active="2"]:after {
  width: 33%;
}

.progressbar[data-active="3"]:after {
  width: 66%;
}

.progressbar:before {
  content: url(https://www.indigo.com/images/icon-cart.png);
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -11px;
  left: 16.666%;
  top: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: left 300ms ease;
  transition: left 300ms ease;
}

.progressbar:not([data-active=""]):before {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: left 2900ms ease, opacity 300ms ease;
  transition: left 2900ms ease, opacity 300ms ease;
}

.progressbar[data-active="1"]:before {
  left: 16.666%;
}

.progressbar[data-active="2"]:before {
  left: 50%;
}

.progressbar[data-active="3"]:before {
  left: 83.333%;
}

.progressbar[data-active=""]:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar" data-active="1">
    <li class="active"><span>Step 1</span></li>
    <li><span>Step 2</span></li>
    <li><span>Step 3</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="cartanime"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un gradiente linear como fondo:

```
.progressbar li.active + li:after {
   background: linear-gradient(to right, green 0%,green 50%,#edeff0 50%,#edeff0 100%)
}
```

De esta forma estableces un fondo verde desde `0%` a `50%` y uno gris desde `50%` hasta `100%`:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 73px;
}

.progressbar {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.progressbar li > * {
  border: 1px dotted rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18823529411764706);
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: rgba(44, 63, 76, 0.6196078431372549);
  top: -70px;
  background-color: rgba(237, 239, 240, 0.61);
}

.progressbar li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  display: block;
  text-align:  center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #edeff0;
}
  
.progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #edeff0;
  top: 4px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
  
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
  
.progressbar li.active span {
  color: green;
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.1);
}

.progressbar li.active:before {
 background-color: green;
 -webkit-transition: background 300ms ease;
 transition: background 300ms ease;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 300ms;
 transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.progressbar li.active + li:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green 0%,green 50%,#edeff0 50%,#edeff0 100%)
}

.progressbar:after {
  content: "";
  height: 4px;
  left: 16.666%;
  background: green;
  top: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: width 300ms ease;
  transition: width 300ms ease;
}

.progressbar[data-active="1"]:after {
  width: 0;
}

.progressbar[data-active="2"]:after {
  width: 33%;
}

.progressbar[data-active="3"]:after {
  width: 66%;
}

.progressbar:before {
  content: url(https://www.indigo.com/images/icon-cart.png);
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -11px;
  left: 16.666%;
  top: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: left 300ms ease;
  transition: left 300ms ease;
}

.progressbar:not([data-active=""]):before {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: left 2900ms ease, opacity 300ms ease;
  transition: left 2900ms ease, opacity 300ms ease;
}

.progressbar[data-active="1"]:before {
  left: 16.666%;
}

.progressbar[data-active="2"]:before {
  left: 50%;
}

.progressbar[data-active="3"]:before {
  left: 83.333%;
}

.progressbar[data-active=""]:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar" data-active="1">
    <li class="active"><span>Step 1</span></li>
    <li><span>Step 2</span></li>
    <li><span>Step 3</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="cartanime"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @AsierVillanueva solo has realizado cambio aquí `.progressbar li.active + li:after` nada más, al ejecutarlo veo que  funciona perfectamente, gracias :)

Comment: Sí. Es el único cambio respecto a tu código